# Facebook access token request gets cancelled

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implement Facebook login in my android app. The problem is that the request to get the access token always gets cancelled when I'm using the native facebook app. When I added this line (forces using a webview):

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
```

The request is successful. Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: share your code how you requesting for access token from app !

Comment: @kapilrajput I managed to solve it by calling the logOut() method once I got the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by calling the `logOut()` of the `LoginManager`. Apparently if the app is still logged in to Facebook, it will cancel the request.